# Fixing the Date Class increment (C++)

Tags: c++

I have made a Library system. But I just checked and my 'Date' is not working properly.

The primary task of this class

```
                                   (1) Increment date
```

Now, I am having an issue in the increment date, it works fine when I am incrementing it to the values up to 25-30. But when I enter 90, it messes up.

```
void increment_date(int num)
    {
        int day;
        int month_new;
        setDay(getDay()+num);


        if(    getDay()>Days_per_Month[getMonth()]     )
        {
            day=getDay()-Days_per_Month[getMonth()];
            setDay(day);
            setMonth(getMonth()+1);
            if(Days_per_Month[getMonth()]>12)
            {
                month_new=1;
                setMonth(month_new);
                setYear(getYear()+1);
            }
        }
        cout<<"Return Date: ";
        Print_Date();
    }
//the code below is outside the class.

const int Date:: Days_per_Month[13]={0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
int Date::checkDay(int testday)     //returntype classname :: funcname (parameteres)
{
    //static const int Days_per_Month[13]={0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    if(testday > 0 && testday <= Days_per_Month[Month])
        return testday;
    if ( Month==2 && testday==29 && (Year%400==0 || (Year%4==0 && Year%100!=0)) )  //for leap year
        return testday;

    cout<<"Day "<<testday<<" invalid. Set to day 1."<<endl;
    return 1;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUh2u.png)

Comment: "it messes up." is not a halpful description of the problem.  Could you please provide an example with values that do not work, explain what does not work, and tell us what you've tried to solve the error ?

Comment: If I enter Value 90 (as increment days). The day goes to 60 (obviously I am subtracting it with a single month). If I enter, a value under 30, it stays fine and shows the accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    setDay(getDay()+num);

    if(    getDay()>Days_per_Month[getMonth()]     )
    {
        day=getDay()-Days_per_Month[getMonth()];
        setDay(day);
        setMonth(getMonth()+1);
```

In the above code, you add `num` to the value returned by `getDay()`, and then you check to see if `getDay()` is greater than the number of days in the current month, and if it is, you try to correct the problem by subtracting the number of days in the current month, and then incrementing the month.

So far, so good, but what if `getDay()` is *still* greater than the number of days in the current month after you've done that subtraction?  (e.g. what if the user enters `300` for the increment-count?)  In that case, you need to do the whole thing again, and keep doing it until `getDay()` is small enough to be a valid day-within-the-month value.  So really a `while` loop is called for, not just an `if`.

Comment: This was the error I was getting. Thanks for the suggestion. I am going to try while loop then.